# Dot in Apache location name requires trailing slash?

Tags: apache-2.2

I noticed that using a dot (.) in Apache Location requires adding trailing slash in URL to work properly.

Anyone knows why this happens, and how to enable it to work without the trailing slash?

Comment: Can you provide some context?  Is this a directory, or some other kind of location - what's your `<Location>` block actually configured as?  What configuration directives are broken when it's not working?

Comment: Here is a sample config file: http://pastie.org/private/25ldarn1gcqgslo2owvzhq. This basically a reverse proxy server with location pointing to physical directory with WSGI.

Comment: So where would the `.` be in this example?